# Dependency Injection, Factory or neither

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have a web application with `Web`, `Business Logic` and `Data Access` layers (all separate projects).

```
MyProject.Web
    /Controllers
    /Views
    ...
MyProject.BusinessLogic
    /Contracts
    /Services <-- implementations
    ...
MyProject.DataAccess
    /Contracts
    /Repositories
    ...
```

In the service layer, for example, I have interfaces for services as well as concrete implementations. In the `Web` project I inject services defined in `BusinessLogic` layer.

Now, I have a caching service (both contract & implementation) in the `BusinessLogic` that is going to be used only in that project. Should I dependency-inject the caching service even though the composition root is in the `Web` project? (Or should I just use a Factory pattern instead?)
Right now in the `BusinessLogic` project I have

```
private readonly ICacheService _cacheService = new CacheService();
```

but this feels wrong to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could have a local factory implemented so that the composition root provides an actual implementation provider. This way the client code relies on the factory while you easily swap implementations and in the actual app the implementation uses a container.

Comment: Are you using Ninject? I can't speak about other technologies like Unity for instance, but with Ninject, it's possible to define implementations of `INinjectModule` (think that was the name) which define the bindings specifically for each project, and load all of those modules in the composition root. Maybe there's something similar available for you?